# Angelika Kratzer's modal bases

Tags: semantics, formal-semantics, modality

In Kratzer’s theory, for each world w, modal base is the set of propositions p such that the speaker knows in w that p is true, e.g. f(w) = {p1, p2, p3}.

Following the standard assumption in possible worlds semantics, a proposition is taken as a set of possible worlds in Kratzer’s theory, e.g. p1 = {w1,w2,w3}, p2 = {w2,w3}, p3 = {w1,w2,w3,w4}.

I just wonder why p is composed of possible worlds? Shouldn't it be that we evaluate p's truth value in possible worlds?

Comment: Is this really a linguistics question? Seems more of a philosophy question to me.

Comment: @curiousdannii Kratzer's theory of the semantics of modals is the dominant one in linguistics. Clearly questions about it therefore are fitting for a linguistics site such as this one. Just about any formal semantics will have an overlap with philosophy.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. It may be dominant within formal semantics, but that is only a tiny part of linguistics. I spent quite some time studying modality and don't remember coming across it.

Comment: I think your questions about Krazter should be merged

Comment: It's dominant in certain formal linguistic areas. It's not a syntactic theory of modality.